# Android SEND_SMS permission not working on Blackberry 10.2.1

Tags: android, permissions, sms, blackberry-10, blocked

I have an android app that users the following permissions :

```
 <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"
  android:maxSdkVersion="21" />
  <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
        android:maxSdkVersion="21" />
```

It works fine on all android devices, when I install it on a blackberry Z30, (from AMAZON app store, or local apk) with Blackberry OS 10.2.1 only the Location permission shows..and the app doesn't send SMS.

Any idea why?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know that since KitKat, you need to put your app has default SMS application.

Read this : [Set default SMS App](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html)

Maybe the BlackBerry 10.2.1 use the same logic.